# Is this card game found in casinos?

Tags: identify-this-game, casino

In the paper [1], the authors write

> "... the problem is equivalent to a card game played in Las Vegas:
>    The cards of a shuffled deck are dealt one at a time and face up.
>   At the same time the player calls the denominations in the order
>   ace, two, three,..., queen, king; ace, two,...
>   A **match** occurs when the player calls the same denomination as the 
>   card dealt; the suits need not match. The player wins if no match occurs."

Is this game actually played in Las Vegas casinos, and if so, what is it called?

[1] F. F. Knudsen and I. Skau, 
*On the Asymptotic Solution of a Card-Matching Problem*,
 Mathematics Magazine 69 (1996), 190-197.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but that sounds sort of like pharo, which has not been in casinos some time as it was proven to not favor the house.

Comment: @AdamP I had trouble finding your reference but [Faro or Pharaoh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faro_(card_game)) seems to be close.

Comment: @Pow-Ian yes that is the game I thinking of. Sorry for the misspelling I was going purely off memory. I do not know if it is the game described by the OP but it sounded similar enough to bring the game to my memory.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to be answered in the comments:
@AdamP I had trouble finding your reference but Faro or Pharaoh seems to be close.